# Exporting to SVG from PowerPoint white bar

Tags: svg, powerpoint

When I export my SVG from powerpoint to svg it is not extending the bg all the way? I need to be a SVG because I am putting this in powerbi and the png the text looks TERRIBLE. SVG I see fixes this, but causes a new error. Attached is ss of my powerpoint and its fine and then when I export.[the way its supposed to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPFW6.png)
[the wrong way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99YdM.png)

I didn't try anything I don't know what to try.